# Forming a tree from a flat array with category id

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree

I have a huge chunk of legacy data in a format that looks somewhat like this:

```
Name         | Bid      
-----------------------
Animal       | 1
Canine       | 11
Dog          | 111
Bulldog      | 1111
Wolf         | 112
Hyena        | 113
Feline       | 12
Cat          | 121
Lion         | 122
```

The `Bid` field is a string that describes the relations of the categories, meaning the data structure looks like this:

```
Animal
  Canine
    Dog
      Bulldog
    Wolf
    Hyena
  Feline
    Cat
    Lion
```

What would be the best way to build an array tree from the data? The source data is one-dimensional which makes it difficult to use recursion. I've been trying to come up with the logic of the loop for a while but haven't come up with a reasonable solution.

Comment: Is the bid data always one number per location? So you wouldn't ever have more than 9 items in any layer of the tree?

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637007/build-an-array-tree-from-flat-array-and-structured-id

Comment: what do you want to do with it? Print it? Or use the structure in another manner?

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty damn sure a Hyena is feline, not canine. (-:

Comment: Berry, I ultimately want to display it in jsTree, meaning I need it in JSON form. That should be simple though, once the data is arranged in a tree form. And Wikipedia says you're right - hyenas are indeed feline. I've always thought they look more like dogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array(
  array('Name' => 'Animal',  'Bid' => '1'  ),
  array('Name' => 'Canine',  'Bid' => '11'  ),
  array('Name' => 'Dog',     'Bid' => '111' ),
  array('Name' => 'Bulldog', 'Bid' => '1111'),
  array('Name' => 'Wolf',    'Bid' => '112' ),
  array('Name' => 'Hyena',   'Bid' => '113' ),
  array('Name' => 'Feline',  'Bid' => '12'  ),
  array('Name' => 'Cat',     'Bid' => '121' ),
  array('Name' => 'Lion',    'Bid' => '122' ),
);


$struct = array(
  'children' => array()
);

foreach ($data as $entry) {
  $parent =& $struct;

  foreach (str_split($entry['Bid'], 1) as $val) {
    if (!isset($parent['children'][$val])) {
      // if not, we create an empty entry
      $parent['children'][$val] = array(
        'entry' => array(),  // no content
        'children' => array()  // no children
      );
    }

    $parent =& $parent['children'][$val];
  }

  $parent['entry'] = $entry;
}

print_r($struct);
```

and using:

```
function render($elements, $depth = 0) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    printf("%s%s\n", str_repeat(' ', $depth * 2), $element['entry']['Name']);
    render($element['children'], $depth + 1);
  }
}

render($struct['children']);
```

you'll get:

```
Animal
  Canine
    Dog
      Bulldog
    Wolf
    Hyena
  Feline
    Cat
    Lion
```